# psycopg2 copy_expert - find number of rows inserted

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

How can I get the count of rows inserted using copy_expert? The below returns 0 even though more 10 records were inserted.

```
    copy_sql = sql.SQL("COPY {} from stdin WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER as ','").format(
        sql.Identifier(table_name))
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=file)
    logger.info(f" rowcount = {cursor.rowcount}")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: What is your psycopg2 version?

Comment: @kyore It is 2.8.4

Comment: quick note: db objects (table names, fields) should be formatted using [psycopg2.sql.Identifier](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier).

Comment: @lonutTicus - Thanks for letting me know. I have updated it.

Comment: The code you have in your question should work. I just tried it using your version of psycopg2 (but with version 12 of postgres)

Comment: Thanks @ShmuelKamensky. It worked. I was reading the file object before passing to this method and missed to reset the file pointer. Hence I was always seeing 0 rows inserted.